# Calculate Balance from Transactions

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
ID  Type    Amount  Created
10  4   30,00   2019-11-29 11:34:54.417
1   1   10,50   2019-11-19 11:34:54.417
3   2   16,50   2019-11-17 11:34:54.417
2   4   11,50   2019-11-15 11:34:54.417
4   6   10,00   2019-11-11 11:34:54.417
5   3   8,60    2019-10-19 11:34:54.417
7   1   21,50   2019-05-19 11:34:54.417
8   4   9,00    2019-04-19 11:34:54.417
9   1   8,00    2019-02-19 11:34:54.417
6   1   1,50    2019-01-19 11:34:54.417
```

Imagine this table keeps an e-wallet and these are Transactions with ID , Type(withdrawals , reversals , deposits etc..) ,Amount and datetime Created.
Lets say that all these 10 transactions refer to a specific Customer. Thus if i run

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Balance
FROM  transactions
WHERE Created <= '20191120'
```

this query will return the Balance of this customer until 2019/11/20.

What i want is to run a select query to this table and keep only the Transactions with Type=4.
E.g.

```
SELECT  ID
    ,   Type
    ,   Amount
    ,   Created
FROM    transactions
WHERE type=4
```

This query returns the following

```
ID  Type    Amount  Created
2   4   11,50   2019-11-15 11:34:54.417
8   4   9,00    2019-04-19 11:34:54.417
10  4   30,00   2019-11-29 11:34:54.417
```

What i really want though is an extra column in this result set that shows the balance of the customer at the point of each  transaction(with Type=4). For example when he did the Transaction with ID = 2 His balance before this(**not counting the current(id=2**) was (1,50+8,00+9,00+21,50+8,60+10,00) , when he did the Transaction with ID = 8 his balance was (1,50+8,00) and so on..

A desired Result set would be

```
  ID    Type    Amount  Created  Balance
2   4   11,50   2019-11-15 11:34:54.417  58,60
8   4   9,00    2019-04-19 11:34:54.417  9,50
10  4   30,00   2019-11-29 11:34:54.417  97,1
```

I want to do this in one Select Query. I have some thoughts of doing it in two steps but that's not my intention, i Just need  to run it once and have all five desired columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking carefully at your desired output, assuming your DBMS supports window functions, you can do this using a pseudo-cumulative sum:

```sql
SELECT ID, Type, Amount, Created, Balance
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Type, Amount, Created, 
    SUM(Amount) OVER(-- Sum "amount" of all rows before current row (exclude current row)
      ORDER BY Created ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING 
  ) AS Balance
  FROM transactions
) src
WHERE type = 4
ORDER BY id
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ebe47/7)

Also, shouldn't the balance for `id=2` be `58,6` and the balance for `id=10` be `97.1`?

Answer (score 0):

You want a cumulative sum and filtering:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY Created) - Amount AS Balance
      FROM  transactions t
      WHERE Created <= '20191120'
     ) t
WHERE type = 4;
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the "Desired Result set" the user is asking for.

Comment: @ravioli simple `SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY Created) - Amount` can fix it and it is much more readable than your solution

Comment: Hmm...I never thought about it that way.  You are right, that is a good suggestion.